# php function pass return to the function again

Tags: php, function, api, loops, instagram

I'm doing in instagram API, and little bit confusing about loop in function.

I try to create code to get all images from instagram user, but the API only give limit to 20 images. And we must do next call to the next page.

I'm using https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API to my application, and here is the function to get images.

```
function getUserMedia($id = 'self', $limit = 0)
{
    $params = array();

    if ($limit > 0) {
        $params['count'] = $limit;
    }

    return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/media/recent', strlen($this->getAccessToken()), $params);
}
```

I try to make a call, the return value is

```
{

"pagination": 

{

"next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/21537353/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxxx&max_id=1173734674550540529_21537353",
"next_max_id": "1173734674550540529_21537353"

}, [.... another result data ....]
```

That the first function result, and produce 20 images.

My Question is:

1. How to pass return from to that function, to that function again using *next_max_id* parameter, so it will looping and using that function again?
2. How to merge the result to be 1 object array?

I'm sorry about my English and my explanation if not good.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: modify your function in this way: `getUserMedia($id = 'self', $limit = 0, $next_max_id=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursive function
and stop that function when next_url found null/empty

Answer (score 0):

From Instagram-PHP-Api documentation it seems to me that you should use **pagination()** method to receive your next page:

```
$photos = $instagram->getTagMedia('kitten');
$result = $instagram->pagination($photos);
```

Just use a condition (if) to verify if $result has content and, if it has, make another call with **pagination()** to request next page. Do it recursively.

But I think it's a good idea to implement without Instagram-PHP-Api using a while loop:

```
$token = "<your-accces-token>";
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=".$token;

while ($url != null) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $photos = json_decode($output);

    if ($photos->meta->code == 200) {

        // do stuff with photos

        $url = (isset($photos->pagination->next_url)) ? $photos->pagination->next_url : null; // verify if there's another page

    } else {    
        $url = null; // if error, stop the loop
    }

    sleep(1000); // to avoid to much requests on Instagram at almost the same time and protect your rate limits API
}
```

Good luck!